# Directory list of only first 2 subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subdirectory

I need a directory listing of only the first 2 subfolders on one of our servers. So, if our network is `"S:\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4"` I need `"S:\sub1\sub2"` in the directory list.

I have `Tree Size professional`, `Karens Dir Print`, and `cmd` prompt. I could create a `.bat` file as well, just don't know the language.

Please help :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by: _"I need `S:\sub1\sub2` in the directory list."_ do you want to see the files in this structure, or only see the particular path?

Comment: I mean I just want the path. My end product should be a directory listing in a .txt file containing the first 2 folders on our server.

Comment: ok, So I need to determine how you want to get to that path. What stops you from just defining `"S:\sub1\sub2"` in the text file? Or do you have something running higher up in the tree which you need to route back to the sub directories?

Comment: No, the first folder on the network is a client name, and the second folder is the project name. There are probably 150 clients and within those folders, several projects per client. I just need a .TXT file that lists out all the clients and projects, like this: S:\client1\projectA
S:\client1\projectB
S:\client1\projectC
S:\client2\projectA
S:\client2\projectB

Comment: Sorry Gherard, I haven't used stackflow before and can't figure out how to put a hard return in my comment. Every time there is a S:\ that directory should be on a new line. I know I can do this in CMD by using the /dir command but that gives me ALL folders, and I only want the first 2.

Comment: either run this from `cmd` by copying `(@for /d %i in ("S:\*") do @for /d %a in ("%i\*") do @echo %~a)>output.txt & start "" notepad.exe output.txt` or by pasting this into notepad and saving it as `get_path.cmd` and then running `get_path.cmd` by double click. `(@for /d %%i in ("S:\*") do @for /d %%a in ("%%i\*") do @echo %%~a)>output.txt & start "" notepad.exe output.txt`

Comment: WOW! This worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the `/Lev:n` option in [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy).

Directly within [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```batch-file
"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" S:\ Null /L /Lev:3 /NFL /NJH /NJS /NC /NS /S /XJ 2> NUL 1> "listing.txt"
```

Or, from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" S:\ Null /L /Lev:3 /NFL /NJH /NJS /NC /NS /S /XJ 2> NUL 1> "listing.txt"
```

---

If you're not satisfied with the leading whitespace, just run it through a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) with the `/F` option, which by default uses spaces and tabs as delimiters. Just get all tokens, and the leading, concurrent, delimiters will be omitted from the results.

Directly within [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```batch-file
(For /F Tokens^=* %G In ('""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" S:\ Null /L /Lev:3 /NFL /NJH /NJS /NC /NS /S /XJ 2>NUL"')Do @Echo %G)>"listing.txt"
```

Or, from [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@(For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" S:\ Null /L /Lev:3 /NFL /NJH /NJS /NC /NS /S /XJ 2>NUL"')Do @Echo %%G)>"listing.txt"
```

---

*In all of the examples above, if you want the file names, instead of the directory names, simply change the `/NFL` option to `/NDL`.*

Comment: I don't see the poster's effort in this question.

Comment: Agreed @AdminOfThings. My reasoning on this occasion was that I posted it after the OP had already received a solution in the comments, and was satisfied with it. There were no existing close votes, so for future searchers/readers I included an answer which performs a similar task in a different way. As I stated in your answer earlier, the decision is yours whether to answer a question, off topic, or otherwise. And the decision to downvote is yours too. Feel free to downvote it, and go through each of my previous answers, doing the same, _(there will be many)_, if you really want to.